# linking problem on linux (can't find the name of the appropriate library)

Tags: c++, c, linux, linker, xmpp

I trying to use a library (http://code.google.com/p/qxmpp/)  but I can't find the name of the library to link it to. I want to understand how can you find out the name of the library to use in the linking parameters.

Comment: Does the library documentation not tell you?

Comment: the documentation don't tell any thing about compiling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like that is a source archive only -- no binaries included.  Have you built the library from it?  Where did the build process put it?  `/usr/lib` or `/usr/local/lib` would be usual suspects, but read the build and install documentation in the package.

Comment: I installed it through apt-get on ubuntu and i found the .a library file "/usr/lib/libqxmpp.a" but linking with libqxmpp don't work

Comment: Post the compile and link command line you are using.  Are you putting `-lqxmpp` on the command line?

Comment: -lqxmpp worked, Thank you very much. is it a rule to name the library with a l prefix ?

Comment: The `-l` command line option tells the linker to add the specified library to the link attempt.  In unix the linker will automatically add `lib` to the given name when looking for the library file.  So if you say `-lfoo` the linker will look for `libfoo.a` or `libfoo.so`.  It looks for the file in the standard library search path, which you can augment by using the `-L` option to add more directories to the path (Think of `-L` as being to the linker and libraries what `-I` is to the compiler and header files.)

Answer (score 1):

Given that the name of the library is `libqxmpp.a` and (as you mention in a comment) that it's in the usual lib directory (`/usr/lib`), you can easily deduce the proper options:

`gcc` and other compilers have an `-l` switch that finds the library based on the name you give it. By default, it will look in the paths given to GCC at build time (usually `/lib` and `/usr/lib`) and any others given to `/etc/ld.so.conf`. If you add the switch `-lX`, it will *prepend* `lib` to the name and by default *append* `.so` and look for any file that looks like `libX.so` in any of the lib directories it knows about.

Working backwards, we can deduce that invoking `gcc` with `-lqxmpp` will look for a file named `libqxmpp.so` (actually, it looks for a few other names, too.) How do we get it to look for a `.a` file? Those `ar`chives (`man ar`) are *static* libraries, so pass the `-static` switch just before the library:

```
gcc -o progname your.o program.o files.o -static -lqxmpp
```

(If you need to link to other libraries, you may need to add `-Wl,-dynamic` for them if you don't want them statically linked or if static libs aren't available.)

Alternatively, you can do this if you know the full path:

```
gcc -o progname your.o program.o files.o /usr/lib/libqxmpp.a
```

... And it works just the same.